# Probability distribution for the momentum of a particle undergoing a collision?

Tags: kinetic-theory-of-gases

### Background

I haven't seen this mauver done before but let's say, I have a thermal gas and I have a molecule with momentum $\vec p$. It undergoes a collision and now has momentum $\vec P$.

Now, due to [molecular chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_chaos#:%7E:text=In%20the%20kinetic%20theory%20of,uncorrelated%2C%20and%20independent%20of%20position.) it should be possible to get the probability distribution function $P$ given $\vec p$ what is the chance it will become $\vec P$ without explicit consideration of the oncoming particle.

### My guess

We consider the ansatz:

$$ P(\vec p, \vec P) = A e^{- \beta |\vec P \cdot \vec p|/m}$$

where A is a normalization constant, $m$ is the mass and $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$ is the standard inverse temperature. Let us assume each molecule undergoes a collision then using the Maxwell distribution my new distribution is:

$$ \tilde P = A' \int_{- \infty}^\infty \int_{- \infty}^\infty \int_{- \infty}^\infty e^{- \beta |\vec P \cdot \vec p|/m} e^{- \beta \vec p^2 /2m} d^3 p \propto e^{-\vec P^2/2m} $$

which is as expected a gaussian/Maxwellian gaussian. ($A'$ is another normalization constant).

Thus, even after collisions the distribution remains the same as it would be worrisome that a different distribution was produced due to collisions.

### Question

Is this the correct distribution for the momentum of a particle undergoing a collision?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761400/probability-distribution-for-the-momentum-of-a-particle-undergoing-a-collision

Comment: Can there be a need of the 3rd integral, addressing distribution of momentum after collision of 2 particles with given m and vector p?

Comment: @Poutnik Its not clear to me why there would be a third integral? Or what it would represent? Btw due to conservation of momentum if the change in one particle is $\Delta p $ the other one will be $- \Delta p$

Comment: The $\Delta \vec p$ can have many possible magnitudes and directions, depending on collision geometry, even for the same initial $\vec p_1$ and  $\vec p_2$ .

Comment: I revoke the 3rd integral note, it was confusion due the way how my phone displayed it. But the note about momentum dispersion stays. For 2 molecules, it is determined also by distribution of collision geometries.